# VsCode: PHP XDebug Cannot evaluate code without a connection

Tags: apache2, php, xdebug

i'm using ubuntu v18.4 with apache2  and php7.3.3 installed. I tried to install php-debug in vscode, but i always get this error when start debugging:

> Cannot evaluate code without a connection

here's my configuration:

**/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

**launch.json**

```
{ 
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```